# SQL Server, create a function return table with variable as parameter

Tags: sql-server, function

I have an issue to call variable from certain tables

For examples, I have a variable of **ID**, **Text1** and **Text2**

I want to create a function to call text1 and text2 separately and then combined them using union

something like:

```
select * form fn_callvariable([Text1])
union
select * form fn_callvariable([Text2])
```

Any suggestion how to the functions should be?

Comment: This sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) You have artificially decided on a path that is likely to be inappropriate for your goal. So step back. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? What is the purpose of your UDF? What are the parameters for it? What does it return? You can't really decide to implement a UDF without well-defined requirements. Your terminology suggests you do not have a strong tsql background. It may be wiser to get local help.

Answer (score 0):

```
select dbo.fn_callvariable([Text1]) from SomeTable
union
select dbo.fn_callvariable([Text2]) from SomeTable
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I tried the query, but it said error 'fn_callvariable' is not a recognized function name. Also, I have no idea have to make variable as parameter for function, while I just used type data (int, string) as parameter

Comment: @RandyAdhitama You have to write the function first.  Once you do, it should work.  Also, I added schema to my answer.